# finding last character shown on a flex spark label

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Among all the options of the spark label, there is none that tells me the last character shown when the text is truncated, is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

For spark Label you can capture the textLines property after updateDisplayList drew the control.

```
package frm.ria.signoff.views.components
{
    import flash.text.engine.TextLine;

    import spark.components.Label;

    import mx.core.mx_internal;

    public class LastShownCharLabel extends Label
    {
        [Bindable]
        public var lastChar:String;

        protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
            if(mx_internal::textLines.length>0)
            {
                var charsInfirstLine:int = TextLine(mx_internal::textLines[0]).rawTextLength;
                if(text) lastChar = text.charAt(charsInfirstLine-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the mxml file for that. please execute the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function onClick():void
        {
            lbl.text = StringUtil.trim(lbl.text);
            output.text = lbl.text.charAt(lbl.text.length -1);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Label id="lbl" text="Sagar    "/>
    <mx:Button click="{onClick();}" label="Click" />
    <mx:TextInput id="output" />
</mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: that returns the last character in the text property of a label regardless if it is visible or not, I would like to know the character before the "..." that appears at the end when it gets truncated.

Comment: I have edited the code.. and just add a single line that trims the text in textinput... now you will get the correct answer.

Comment: still the same result, have in mind that I'm asking about the spark label, not the mx textinput.

Comment: Now is it ok? I have changed the textinput to Label..... and sorry for that because FLEX 4 is not installed in my PC so i can't give you the result of spark label.. but i am sure that similar method is used for that.

Comment: well, I did test it on label, the result was as I said, the last character in the whole text property, not the last one shown.
Maybe it is one of those things taken out when migrated to spark.